# What do I need to do to run a TcpLwip simulation in Omnet++

Tags: omnet++, lwip

I am trying to simulate the lwIP example simulation on OMNET 5.6.1. I am using INET 4.2.4. The simulation I am trying to run can be found at inet/examples/inet/nclients/omnetpp.ini When I try to run it, it gives me the following error:

> "Class "inet::TcpLwip" not found -- perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module()/Define_Channel()--in module (omnetpp::cModules) NClients (id=1), during network setup."

I am new to OMNET++ and will appreciate your guidance on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

By default the LWiP feature is not turned on in INET. You should either open the INET project's properties dialog in the IDE and on the OMNeT++ page find the Project Fetures list and enable TcpLwip, or from the command line (standing in the INET directory) execute `opp_featuretool enable TcpLwip` and then call `make makefiles` and then rebuild.